# How to change TVirtualStringTree Node Icon when that Node is expanded

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

This sounds like a stupid question but I have tried everything I can think of without success.  How can I change the Icon image of a VirtualStringTree Node when that node is expanded. i.e. when Node is collapsed I want to show a closed folder icon and when its expanded I want to show an Open folder icon.

In GetImageIndex I cannot see how to tell if the node is expanded or not.  Kind only tells me when it is selected.

Answer (score 2):

The `TBaseVirtualTree` has `Expanded` property to check wether the given node is expanded or not:

```
procedure TForm1.VTGetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
          Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex; var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: Integer);
begin
  if Sender.Expanded[Node] then begin
     ...
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Node: PVirtualNode;` parameter of the `OnGetImageIndex()` event can tell you through it `States` property whether it is expanded or not.

```
procedure TForm1.VSTGetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex; var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: TImageIndex);
begin
  if vsExpanded in Node.States then
    // select image as needed
  ...
end;
```

Background:

From the source (unit `VirtualTrees`)

```
TVirtualNodeState = (
  ...
  vsExpanded,          // Set if the node is expanded.
  ...
);
```

Comment: I would consider node's properties as an implementation detail, for most (all?) things there is a method which is meant to retrieve given information.

Comment: I would prefer using `Expanded` property as like @ain pointed out, node `States` is supposed to be an implementation detail.